# Mongoose Aggregate Return to REST API - Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, express, mongoose

I am trying to set the result of my aggregate call from mongodb to a rest api endpoint. The goal is to get the count of the number of times each manager is in the collection. Below are my dependencies:

```javascript
"body-parser": "^1.14.2",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"mongoose": "^4.4.2",
"nodemon": "^1.8.1",
```

Mongoose Schema:

```javascript
var projectSchema = new Schema({
 client: String,
 project: String,
 series: String,
 manager: String,
 pieceCount: Number,
 dateShipped: Date,
 comments: String,
 items: [{description: String, barcode: Number, quantity: Number, box:
             Number,returned: Boolean, dateReturned: Date}]});

Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

Aggregate Call:

```javascript
var getTotalManagers = function () {
 Project.aggregate([ 
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$manager',
        "total": {$sum:1}}}],
    function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
           /* return (JSON.stringify(res)); (what is used when not writing to
                console */
        }
    });
  };

 getTotalManagers();
```

This returns the desired results to the console:

```javascript
 [{"_id":"Fname Lname","total":1},{"_id":"Fname Lname","total":1},    
 {"_id":"Fname Lname","total":4},{"_id":"Fname Lname","total":2},   
 {"_id":"Fname Lname","total":2}]
```

Rest API Call:

```javascript
 router.get('/totals',getTotalManagers);
```

I get this error message when trying to access the api call:

```javascript
 {
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"totals\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
   "value": "totals",
   "path": "_id"
  }
```

What is the proper way to set this to a rest api endpoint?  I feel like that is the issue since the aggregate call is working to the console.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: That error is coming from code you have not listed here. Are you trying to re-cast the aggregate results into a mongoose model? You are certainly doing something else somewhere at least. Also your aggregate statement as listed here cannot possibly return the data you say it does. As listed it would just return one document with a count for the whole collection.

Comment: Before you try and paste code in comments. Don't. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35306209/edit) link on your question instead.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you could do that. I updated the aggregate function.